# how to get the id that is associated with a username that is stored in another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy data from an old table to a new one listed below in MYSQL

`test.adminpasswordreset` (table that is getting an insert)

```
TOKEN(VARCHAR)   ADMINID(INT)   TIMEIN   ISUSED
```

Need to grab the `ID` out of the `user` table for the `adminid` in the password reset

`test.userprofile`

```
ID(INT)     USERNAME(VARCHAR)
```

What would be the correct query to select the id from the `userprofile`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO AdminPasswordReset(Token, AdminID, TimeIn, Issued)
SELECT SHA1(RANDOM()), ID, NOW(), NULL FROM UserProfile WHERE UserName = "test"
```